# How do I fix TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is:

```
hwa = b'|\x04\x06\r$>'

msg = '\xff' * 6 + hwa * 16
print(msg)
```

but I am getting the following error:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: What are you hoping to get out? Bytes or a unicode string?

Comment: i am expecting Bytes

Comment: Then you can change `'\xff'` to `b'\xff'` and use bytes consistently.

Comment: this is working. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
'\xff' * 6 + hwa * 16
```

is mixing up strings (`'\xff'`) and bytes (`hwa`), making it ambiguous what you are trying to do.

If you want bytes as your output, put `b'\xff'` instead of `'\xff'`, so you use bytes consistently:

```
hwa = b'|\x04\x06\r$>'

msg = b'\xff' * 6 + hwa * 16
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `decode` function :

```
hwa = b'|\x04\x06\r$>'
msg = '\xff' * 6 + hwa.decode() * 16
print(msg)
```